# Why are my brush strokes in sculpting not smooth but leaves dents

Tags: sculpting

So im having some issues with sculpting and looking for a solution is difficult. Im in sculpting and im trying to make scratches on an axe head. I make strokes but they are not smooth but look more like im making a row of dents. I have scaled the object and remeshed and played with the brush settings but no luck. I am using a XP-Pen. Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this please? Left is me going slow and right is me going fast.
[image]

Comment: What's the brush's *Stroke Method* set to?

Answer (score 0):

go to stroke > an change to space and set spacing lower then what it is. (5% or lower)
also it might help to set spacing distance to view.

[image]

Comment: Sorted. Thank you very much.